# Reverse foreign keys with django-import-export

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I have the following models where each project has a specific set of permissions.

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    possession_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    bank = models.ManyToManyField('Bank')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Permissions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class ProjectPermission(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    permission = models.ForeignKey('Permissions')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project.name
```

I want to import/export data from a csv to this model. How to I reference the permission from the project model in the Resource Admin subclass?

I can access the permission through

```
project.projectpermission_set.all()
```

if project is a Project object.

Comment: and what's your question? The question mark is on a statement. And the following phrase is an affermative statement as well. Please explain.

Comment: How do I add the permission data to the project data when I download the project csv?

Comment: how many project permissions do you need per project? More than one? (as it stands). Otherwise use a one-to-one relationship for both projectpermission an permission

Comment: Yes, the project permissions are more than one. Currently there are 5 but they may increase in future.

Comment: you create a project object. You save it. Then you create a permission object, then you save it. Then you create a projectpermisison object, populating the project and permission fields with the two previously created objects. Then you save that.

Comment: Yes, this is the flow. I am perfectly fine with the creation of data. But I am stuck on exporting it. I can refer to a fk using the double underscore but how do i refer to the projectpermission objects?

Comment: if you want to make a query on Project objects, following the relationship, for example use  Project.objects.filter(projectpermission__value='whatevervalue'). See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for further info on how to name the relationship more conveniently

Comment: I don't want to query anything. I want to export data using django-import-export.

Comment: Cool, I get that, but this doen't solve the problem. How am I supposed to do this with django-import-export?

Answer (score 0):

Answering you question

> How to I reference the permission from the project model?

if you want to make a query on Project objects filtering on the permission, use:

```
Project.objects.filter(projectpermission__permissions__name='whatevervalue').
```

Viceversa, querying the permission objects filtering on the project:

```
Permissions.objects.filter(projectpermission__project__name='whatever')
```

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for further info on how to name the relationship more conveniently

Comment: fantastic. Then edit your question and enable people to help you out

Answer (score 0):

I overwrote the after_import_row-method of the ModelResources to parse and create the reverse-related Models. In my case it worked out quiet well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dehidrate_permissions`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export) and then, as @Pynchia said,

```
Project.objects.filter(projectpermission__permissions__name='whatevervalue').
```